# confusion with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, restful-authentication

I am currently trying out restful_authentication in rails. This is my routes.rb file

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
map.register '/register', :controller => 'users', :action => 'create'
map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
map.resources :users
map.resource :session
map.resources :products
```

This is my SessionsController which handles the login and logout

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  # render new.erb.html
  def new
  end

  def create
    logger.error("Inside create")
    logout_keeping_session!
    user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
    if user
      # Protects against session fixation attacks, causes request forgery
      # protection if user resubmits an earlier form using back
      # button. Uncomment if you understand the tradeoffs.
      # reset_session
      self.current_user = user
      new_cookie_flag = (params[:remember_me] == "1")
      handle_remember_cookie! new_cookie_flag
      redirect_back_or_default('/')
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in successfully"
    else
      note_failed_signin
      @login       = params[:login]
      @remember_me = params[:remember_me]
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout_killing_session!
    flash[:notice] = "You have been logged out."
    redirect_back_or_default('/')
  end

protected
  # Track failed login attempts
  def note_failed_signin
    flash[:error] = "Couldn't log you in as '#{params[:login]}'"
    logger.warn "Failed login for '#{params[:login]}' from #{request.remote_ip} at #{Time.now.utc}"
  end
end
```

I noticed that there is no index action. hence http://localhost:3000/sessions should throw an unknown action error and it did. Then I went to the login page i.e. the :new action in sessionscontroller. I looked up for the form submit url and i found it to be 
[image] 
and upon submitting the url shown in firebug was 
[image]

**How did the url redirect to the correct action? i.e. http://localhost:3000/sessions to http://localhost:3000/sessions/new**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map.resource session` line automatically creates restful routes, with the actions matching up as follows:

```
Verb   Path           Action
------------------------------
GET    /session/new   new
POST   /session       create
GET    /session       show
GET    /session/edit  edit
PUT    /session       update
DELETE /session       destroy
```

Since it's a singular resource, all the paths use `/session`, not `/sessions`, so a `GET` request to `/sessions` will fail. Also, a `GET` request to `/session` will trigger the `show` action, not the `index` action (a singular resource doesn't have an `index` action).

Check out the "Singular Resources" section at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (it's for Rails 3, but the same idea still applies).